# PowerPivot relations witht the same columns from 2 excels

Tags: powerpivot

How do I powerpivot 2 excel files with the exact same column information.  It comes from 2 different production machines and the information is the same.  There is just too many columns (same) and rows to just copy and paste and put in to a pivot table.  I got an error message "the relationship cannot be created because each column contains duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Power Query to append the two tables and load that appended table into the data model. Relationships don't work for that kind of scenario.